# redeploy of worker role should not change the VM

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, azure-worker-roles

i have one application which requires lot of setting to run the worker role
i have concern on the when we redeploy the worker role will it change the VM...?

if it change the VM then all the VM related setting file are need to be re-installed and reconfigured. I am trying to install the FFMPEG on the VM where the worker role will be installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always assume that your worker role's VM will change unexpectedly. Any OS configurations you depend on should be part of your worker role's installation process via startup scripts and never be done manually.

Why?

1. When you upgrade, the VM may change depending on how you upgrade.
2. The physical hardware that your VM runs on may experience a failure (or upgrade) and can go down at any moment. In many of these cases, Azure will provision a new VM and install your worker role to it and bring it up.
3. Operating Systems routinely have updates installed on them and these may trigger the above-mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Worker roles in Windows Azure are essentially `Stateless Virtual Machines`. What that means is that any changes you make after the VM is deployed will be lost when new code is deployed (this would include installing software by connecting to the the VM via RDP) or the VM is recycled.

I would recommend doing the installation of the software you need in the worker role using [`Start Up Tasks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh180155.aspx). This way the software you wish to install are part of your deployment package and Windows Azure will install the software (and other tasks defined in start up tasks) before the role starts.

Comment: Hah, exactly my thoughts!